# Generate aurelia route with parameters and open in new browser tab

Tags: aurelia, router

I need to open a page in new tab with defined parameters.

Before I used only one parameters and it works fine:

```
window.open(this.theRouter.generate('transactionDetails', { id: id }), '_blank');
```

But now I need to add two more parameters.
I tried the following:

```
window.open(this.theRouter.generate('transactionDetails', { id: id, localtimezone: this.localTimeZone, reporttimezone: this.reportTimeZone }), '_blank');
```

But as result I can see in URL this:

```
http://localhost:54072/index.html#/transactionDetails/28789?localtimezone=3&reporttimezone=0
```

What I do wrong? How I can generate url with some parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would the desired output look like? Could you provide an example of an URL that is formatted how you want it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide how to pass parameters.
The way your example looks it seems your route declares the "id" parameter.
If you declare parameters, the most consistent way is to declare every parameter in an analogous way:

`route: "transactionDetails/:id/:localtimezone/:reporttimezone",` 
this way you get something like this:

`#/transactionDetails/123/1608260750758/1608260750758`

another way is to use query string and not use router params:

`route: "transactionDetails",`

this way, you get the url: `#/transactionDetails?id=123&localtimezone=1608260810884&reporttimezone=1608260810884`

a working example is available at

https://codesandbox.io/s/aurelia-router-demo-forked-wyszo?file=/src/app.js:356-384

Regards.

Cristian